# How to trace cpu/memory usage for a process in linux?

Tags: linux, memory, centos, cpu-usage

I want to trace my Node.js app.. I need to see how much of cpu/memory it's taking... how to do this in linux CENTOS... Solutions with log are welcome

Comment: Type `top` in your console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a monitoring software like collectd.